# How to trigger click on an anchor

Tags: javascript

My interface has buttons for next/previous month. Clicking on them, I rebuild the request path (I can see in Firebug that the `href` attribute is correctly assigned), but I can't trigger the `click` event.

The jQuery code is in a Drupal behavior:

```
Drupal.behaviors.foo = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
```

I call the following function:

```
function simulate_click() {
  var newPath = <the-right-path>;
  var anchor = $('a.domaine:first', context);
  anchor.attr("href", newPath);
```

but none of the following statements triggers the click:

```
  anchor.mousedown();
  anchor.trigger('mousedown');
  anchor.click();
  anchor.trigger('click');
```

Is there something special with jQuery in Drupal that I miss ?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Can you verify that `anchor` is bound to the `<a>` tag? (Set a breakpoint and inspect the value.) It looks like you're doing it right but could the function run before the `<a>` is in the DOM?

Comment: @Erin: jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: @cleaver: `anchor` indeed contains the right `<a>`, has `anchor.attr()`performs as intended.

Comment: The workaround I found is to modify the two button tags. Initially, they were `<button>` in a Bootstrap button group and now they are `<a>` with their `href`attribute dynamically built on page loading. Works nicely.    But I remain curious understanding how to trigger an event in Drupal :-)

Comment: @amuli: I'm sure I've done exactly what you're trying to do. Sounds like some odd edge case.